# exist db user registration with xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

I'm trying to create a user registration form and create collection upon registration. 
I tried following code, but when i try to execute  i get this error:
**HTTP 400 Bad Request** and page cannot be displayed. Here is the code:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";
declare namespace response="http://exist-db.org/xquery/response";
declare namespace xdb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";
declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html indent=yes";
declare variable $database-uri as xs:string { "xmldb:exist:///db" };
declare variable $redirect-uri as xs:anyURI { xs:anyURI("login.xql") };

   declare function local:header() as node(){
<div style="background-color:#b0c4de; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
<h1>test</h1>
</div>
};

declare function local:footer() as node(){
<div style="background color:#eee; height: 1%; padding:20px; border: 1px solid black;">
<p>PROJECT</p>
</div>
};      

declare function local:reg($user as xs: string) as element()?
{
let $password := request:get-parameter("password", "")
let $password2 := request:get-parameter("password2", "")
return
    if (not(xdb:exists-user($user))) then ( 
    xdb:create-collection($database-uri, $user),
    xdb:create-user($user, $password, "guest", ()),
    response:redirect-to($redirect-uri)
    ) else
        <p>User already exists!</p>
};

declare function local:do-reg() as element()?
{
    let $user := request:get-parameter("user", ())
    return
        <p>{$user}</p>
        if($user) then
            local:reg($user)
            else ()
};

<html>
<head><title>Registration</title>

</head>
 <body>
 {local:header()}
  <h1>Forma for reg</h1>
  <form action="{request:get-uri()}">
  User Name: <br />
  <input type="text" name="user" size="20" />
  <br />
   Password: <br />
    <input type="password" name="password" size="20" />
  <br />
   Confirm: <br />
    <input type="password" name="password2" size="20" />
  <br />

  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" />
  </form>
  {local:do-reg()}
  {local:footer()}
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help, i'm beginner in xquery and exist db. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, In exist you can't register new user if you are not in db group of premissions.
So what needs to be done is to create a new user for you collection, and give him right premissions, then you need to login with that user in order to register/create new user.

```
xmldb:login('/db/yourcollection', $admin, $password)
                           .
                           .
                           .
                    your registration code
```

the problem with this is that you put admin user and password in your .xql document - and that is not a good idea. But you can use:

> util:base64-encode

and

```
util:base64-decode
```

to encode and decode you password. so how i did it is like this:

system:as-user((util:base64-decode("bXBhcmF2YWM=")),(util:base64-decode("cGFzcw==")), (
    if (not(xdb:exists-user($user))) then ( 
    xdb:create-collection($database-uri, $user),
    xdb:create-user($user, $pass, 'user', ()),
    response:redirect-to($redirect-uri)
    ) else

User exists!

) )

Also there is another way to do this, even more secure, take a look at [this example](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/demo/examples/urlrewriting/index.html)